# Changing Column Names in R or not using Auto-Generated values

Tags: r

OK, I'm new to R so please be gentle.  I have a dataset that I access via API.  It has descriptive column names already in it.  However, when I import it the column names default to V1, V2, .... V18 and row 1 of the data is the actual descriptive column names {ID, Duration, Timestamp, ...}.

How can I get the column names to be the descriptive ones rather than these apparently auto-generated V#'s?

Comment: `header = TRUE` in whatever function you are using to read the data

Comment: Thank you Richard.  I'm using the GetURL function from the RCURL package to access the API.  It writes the data as a string.  Then I use read.table to transform the string into a table which is where the weird V1, V2,...column names show up.  When I add the header = TRUE parameter to the read.table function I says, rightly, "no lines available in input".

Comment: You may want to try `XML::readHTMLTable()` on the URL.  You will need the XML package installed.  Can we have the URL?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't give you access to the api it requires authentication and the data actually belongs to a customer.  I can give you a snippet though.

Comment: [1] "\"id\",\"duration\",\"timestamp\",\"gender\",\"totalFaceSeconds\",\"attention\",\"engagement\",\"sentiment\",\"positive\",\"negative\",\"neutral\",\"anger\",\"contempt\",\"disgust\",\"fear\",\"joy\",\"sadness\",\"surprise\"\n\"29192c40-4f88-cf31-92c8-545004f10336\",\"30.0\",\"0\",\"FEMALE\",\"13\",\"1.0\",\"0.1960399144063954\",\"0.36114759724872375\",\"1.012803753260739\",\"1.7916002105934554\",\"10.195596036145806\",\"0.16218054983772182\",\"0.5519610232909892\",\"0.4580025835719351\",\"0.39209044064081255\",\"1.012803753260739\",\"0.2273656132519967\",\"0.0\"\n

Comment: So if we call that ^^^ `x`, then try `read.csv(text = x)`

Comment: BANG!  Thanks Richard that worked perfectly.  If there's a way to give kudos on stackoverflow expect one from me.

Comment: Well I could just post that answer and you can accept it then we both get kudos.  Haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment above and the included string, you can simply use

```
df <- read.csv(text = x)
head(names(df))
# [1] "id"               "duration"         "timestamp"        "gender"          
# [5] "totalFaceSeconds" "attention"
```

where `x` is

```
x <- "\"id\",\"duration\",\"timestamp\",\"gender\",\"totalFaceSeconds\",\"attention\",\"engagement\",\"sentiment\",\"positive\",\"negative\",\"neutral\",\"anger\",\"contempt\",\"disgust\",\"fear\",\"joy\",\"sadness\",\"surprise\"\n\"29192c40-4f88-cf31-92c8-545004f10336\",\"30.0\",\"0\",\"FEMALE\",\"13\",\"1.0\",\"0.1960399144063954\",\"0.36114759724872375\",\"1.012803753260739\",\"1.7916002105934554\",\"10.195596036145806\",\"0.16218054983772182\",\"0.5519610232909892\",\"0.4580025835719351\",\"0.39209044064081255\",\"1.012803753260739\",\"0.2273656132519967\",\"0.0\"\n"
```